# Changing the Unity Color Gradient Inspector Field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm using Unity's color gradient property field in a custom inspector drawer like this:

```
SerializedProperty colorGradient = property.FindPropertyRelative("colorGradient");
EditorGUI.PropertyField(pos, colorGradient);
```

This initializes with no valid gradient being selected. I'd like to preload the first one in the project set before the user selects one from the stored set or creates a new one.

With other `PropertyField` types like `IntSlider`, it's simple to access its `.intValue` member for setting it directly. From the debugger, I can see a non-public `.gradientValue` member, but I don't see any relevant value member for the `colorGradient` type that is accessible to set directly from a script. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show the full script? What exactly is the issue? I just tested it with a CustomEditor and it works how I would expect .... Do you mean you want to assign a default value to your field?

Comment: That's really it. It brings up the gradient property in the custom inspector drawer. Yes, it works fine but I want to set the default gradient to something other than a null instance that is a blank, white gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to set the default gradient to something other than a null instance that is a blank, white gradient.

Since your field is serialized it will not be `null` (otherwise you would already get a `NullReferenceException`). It is rather simply the default value used by `new Gradient()`.

In order to have a default gradient in the Inspector you actually wouldn't need a special editor or property drawer. You only would need to assign some default values to it when you declare the field in your class:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Gradient exampleGradient = new Gradient
    {
        alphaKeys = new[]
        {
            new GradientAlphaKey(0, 0f),
            new GradientAlphaKey(1, 1f)
        },

        colorKeys = new[]
        {
            new GradientColorKey(Color.red, 0f),
            new GradientColorKey(Color.cyan, 0.5f),
            new GradientColorKey(Color.green, 1f)
        }
    };
}
```

[image]